# Saving an image to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
Create Proc CrearNuevoImagen
    @imagen image       
AS

INSERT INTO 
    Imagenes(imagen)

VALUES(
    @imagen
    )
```

I see that @imagen is of type 'image'.

My question is save that I have an .jpg image, on my front-end (my asp.net website code), how could I convert the .jpg image to fit into the 'image'-type column? Or does the SQL Server automatically do this for me?

Comment: sigh. You do realize that people filter questions based on tags?  By using good tags, your question will be highlighted or show up in rss feeds for people who are likely to know how to answer them?

Comment: Don't use "IMAGE" anymore - with SQL Server 2005 and newer, use VARBINARY(MAX) instead. IMAGE will be removed from SQL Server some time soon

Comment: @marc_s: and good riddance too.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your image object to a MemoryStream.  Then you can take the byte array out of the memory stream and pass that to SQL Server to save it in your "image" or "varbinary" column.

Comment: So, all I have to do is convert the "Image" to a "byte array" and the SQL will accept that into the 'image'-type column?

Comment: Yes, and you'll use the GetBytes() method to read the data out with your SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 2):

The image column type is just a binary container; SQL Server doesn't interpret or modify the data you store there at all.

See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377078

Answer (score 1):

The IMAGE type is just a name for a type that can store a byte array. It is now deprecated and you should use the VARBINARY(MAX) type instead. Saving JPG files into the back end database is actually a bit more complex if you care about performance, because of the need to avoid these relatively large files to be copied into memory. Have a look at [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) for an example of efficient streaming of image files stored in SQL Server BLOB fields.

Comment: +1 for IMAGE type is now deprecated., `image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server` from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx